# Is a local CGEventRef considered a pointer?

Tags: c++, macos, oop, pointers, memory

When I was making keyboard events with a local `CGEventRef`, I noticed that even though it was not a pointer, you could "edit" its properties with functions, like so:

```
CGEventRef eventRef = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(....);
CGEventSetFlags(eventRef, ...);
CGEventSetType(eventRef, kCGEventKeyDown);
```

Then you `Post`the event. I know that if you do something like this;

```
Player p; //assume Player has an x property and a y property (both public)
p.x = 100000; p.y = -431;
void changePlayerPosition(Player player__, int x, int y){
   player__.x = x; player__.y = y;
}
changePlayerPostion(10, 43);
std::cout << p.x << p.y; //prints x=1000000 y=-431 even though we tried to edit the values to 10 and 43 in the function
```

The values do not change even though we edited them in the `changePlayerPosition` function. I know you can fix this by getting the address of `player__` in the argument i.e `Player &player__`.

That was an example. I guess my real question is, how is `CGEventRef eventRef`properties like its `flag, type, etc.`edited without passing in a pointer or address in functions such as `CGEventSetFlags, CGEventSetType, etc.` Thank you so much!

P.S some code would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

documentation is here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CGEventRef

quoting:

```
typedef struct __CGEvent *CGEventRef;
```

it's a pointer.

Comment: If possible where would I find the actual struct definition of `__CGEvent`?